# WebSockets, ByteBuffer and PC Architecture

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, raspberry-pi, bytebuffer

I am using websockets between a windows machine and a Raspberry Pi. I use the @OnMessage from websocket-api to send some binary data from the windows machine to the raspberry pi machine. The specs are as given below.

```
Windows 7 64 bit
JDK 1.8_u05 64 bit
Glassfish 4.0 open source edition

Raspberry PI 32 bit (debian)
JDK 1.8.0 b132
Stand alone websocket
```

Now the problem, WebSocket connection from Windows machine to raspberry PI sends binary data as an all zero byte array if

1. I change the Glassfish server to tomcat
2. I change the jdk version from 1.8.0_u5 to anything other than this
3. I change the glassfish version from 4.0 to 4.1

I am clueless why this is happening. Can these be related? How do I at least find out cause of this?

EDIT : I have debugged, used fiddler, wireshark (at windows), logs and have found that the data is going from Windows is proper - Raspberry PI is receiving it as just zeroes (logs only).

Comment: There are ways to use a debugger so you can step through the code and find the place that causes this. [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q2), [GlassFish](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_applications_for_GlassFish_Server))

Comment: @zapl the data that goes from windows is [x,y,z] - the data at raspberry is [0,0,0]

Comment: I'm a little confused now. So changing versions on windows side does not change the data sent but the PI will still suddenly evaluate that to all 0s? The data on the wire does not change vs the result changes sounds impossible.

Comment: Yea buddy, I dont know what is happening between the network. Can wifi be a problem?

Comment: Bad wifi can drop the connection, nothing should be able to alter the data because there are checksums and such that make sure that every bit is received as sent or discarded as corrupt.

Comment: Websocket is still a rather new protocol and [this](http://uberconf.com/blog/reza_rahman/2014/08/spotlight_on_glassfish_4_1__6_java_api_for_websocket_1_1) says that glassfish 4.1 updated to a newer implementation. So maybe some special new feature or added support for something in the protocol causes that problem.